# TREB IDX (MLS) integration with Property Real Estate Listings in PHP

Tags: php, idx, mls

I need to integrate IDX MLS into my website. I have gone through my 3rd Party Applications like Realtyna, kvcore, etc But their plans are too high can Someone help me out How can I create API in PHP I want to fetch Toronto, CA Listings on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has several IDX plugins: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/idx/

Comment: I mentioned it in PHP I know many WordPress plugin but client is not interested in WordPress